# How to retrive colors from database in to a text box and change when ever necessary

Tags: javascript, php, css

How to retrieve colors from database in to a text box and change when ever necessary and post like  a preview to next page .

I had used

```
<div><table><tr><td  style="background-color:#ffff00; fore-color:white; font-size:15pt;">Some text From data base</td></tr></table></div>
```

The above i had kept in database.The div color is fetching fine my problem arises when i need to post the color of div to next page or change the Color using color picker code...Please help me out in this

Comment: Er... No code, no answer! What have you done?

Comment: can you please explain ? what exactaly  you want

Comment: I want to fetch data from data base to html page with text color and Background Color..If the user doesn't like the color which is fetched from database we should provide him the option to change using Color picker.Now my problem is I how to fetch the text from database with Color.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to retrieve the background color of the td: add an id to the td element for easy retrieval:

```
<div><table><tr><td id="colorpot" style="background-color:#ffff00; fore-color:white; font-size:15pt;">Some text From data base</td></tr></table></div>
```

then you can get the background color of it using:

```
var bgColor = document.getElementById('colorpot').style.backgroundColor;
var textColor = document.getElementById('colorpot').style.color;
var text = document.getElementById('colorpot').textContent;
```

you can pass this variable to other pages, also if you want to change the color with the colorpicker (assuming its id is "colorPicker"):

```
document.getElementById('colorpot').style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;
```

and you can set these properties with data from server using:

```
document.getElementById('colorpot').style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
document.getElementById('colorpot').style.color = textColor;
document.getElementById('colorpot').textContent = text;
```

considering data you receive from server for background color, text color and the text are bgColor, textColor and text, respectively.

Comment: Can u Please help me out the syntax to store a text with text Color and back ground color ..<div><table><tr><td id="colorpot" style="background-color:#ffff00; fore-color:white; font-size:15pt;">text in database</td></tr></table></div>

Comment: I have updated my answer with variables for each background color, text color and the text. hope this helps.

Comment: Can we fetch the text with color from database if so please help me out in this sir

Comment: Well, without knowing how is your server side code, how this page is served, if there is specific api end point to get the colors and text, it's not possible. But, considering you have these information as variable, I update my answer to show how to set these in javascript.